# jQuery code to pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to convet this jquery code to pure js code but i failed

```
$('.number-wrapper').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

this is my try

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("number-wrapper");
    for(var i =0; i<x.length;i++){

}
```

i cant continue from the prop method 
can someone help with this

Comment: post your trying

Answer (score 0):

The `.prop()` is, first and foremost, setting a property of the HTML element. In your case, it's setting `Counter` to 0, which translates to:

```
<div Counter=0></div>
```

And if you want to do this with raw JavaScript, you can just put this inside your `for` loop:

```
x[i].Counter = 0;
```

That code is doing more things after that, but I'll leave it to you to find it out in jQuery's documentation.

But this is bad code and I advise against it. Use jQuery. If it's heavy, use jQuery Lite. If you're just learning, go ahead and crash as much code as you can! :)

Answer (score -1):

jQuery is an [open source project](https://github.com/jquery/jquery), you can easily watch the source of the functions you're using and us it....

But,

WHY would you want to do this...?

Comment: While historically jQ was very useful in that it served as a common ground on which front-end developers could rely on to overcome the jungle of quirks in the different browsers, modern browsers have improved drastically and now all support most of it's features in native js. Thus the role of jQ has been outlived and it has become more of an extra bloaty legacy dependency than anything else.